# CSS float styling

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following code:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

div.menu
{
    float:left;
}

div ul.menu 
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    float:left;
}

div li.menuitem
{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    color:red;
    background:green;
    padding:5px;
}

div li.menuitem:hover{
    background:yellow;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menuitem"> first </li>
    <li class="menuitem"> second </li>
    <li class="menuitem"> third </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The result looks like :

[image]

What's causing the gap in the left of 'first' ?

Thanks.

Comment: A native browser property give any `ul` a padding to the left. Try give `padding:0;` to the `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers add padding to `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements typically.  You can set a `-webkit-padding-start` on Chrome, but it's probably easier to just use `padding-left: 0` or `padding: 0` on the `<ul>` element.  Also look out for `-webkit-margin-before` and `after`.

You may also want to set: `list-style-type: none`

http://jsfiddle.net/7n4Xn/1

Answer (score 2):

`ul` by default creates some padding space on the left.

```
li ul{
    padding:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDvF4/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of the browsers default styles.
You could use an [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `list-style:none` and reset any paddings/margins to the `ul`. So the style of the `ul` becomes:

```
div ul.menu {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6umn8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

add `padding: 0px;` to your `.menu` class

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
padding: 0px;
```

to your     div ul.menu

so it would look like this:

```
div ul.menu 
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
}
```